# Node-red:node-function - missing "null" value in if condition

Tags: node.js, if-statement, null, node-red

I'm using Node-Red and in node function I have:

```
  ...  
  res = dataTransform.transform();  
  //critic case: res = [{"pressure":null}];  
  key = Object.keys(res[0]);  
  if(res[0][[key]]!=null)  
  {  
   ...   
   console.log("res:   ", [key]+":"+res[0][[key]]);  
  }
```

on console.log I have always:

> res:    0:[object Object]

And it enters in if-statement always (also when the "res[0][[key]]" is null).

What was I mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array containing the keys of the Object. Your code is using that entire array rather than a value from within it.

In order to get to the value of `pressure`, you would use:

```
var keys = Object.keys(res[0]);
var key = keys[0];
if (res[0][key] != null) {
    console.log(res[0][key]);
}
```